# Need some help with a question involving the Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus

Been struggling with this question:

Given: $c_{ij}=\epsilon_{ijk}a_k$

I have to show that $a_k=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{kij}c_{ij}.$

I was thinking of multiplying both sides by some epsilon, but not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's C? Is it an unknown?

Comment: yeah it is unknown

Comment: Do you know how to express $\epsilon_{ijk}\,\epsilon_{krs}$ by way of
$\delta$'s?

Comment: Have you checked out the examples at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol ?

Comment: Yeah I have been looking at that, I noticed that if I multiply both sides by an epsilon I can get to (on the left hand side) $\epsilon_{ijl}\epsilon_{ijk}a_k$ which would then equal $2\delta_{lk}a_k$ but not sure what to do afterwards

Comment: Just substitute the expression for c_ij and do the summation over I and I which gives a delta function and a factor 2

Comment: but how do you know if the delta function is equal to one?

Comment: @A.Pavlenko - The [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) is either one or zero, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{kij}c_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{kij}\epsilon_{ijl}a_l =\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{ijl}a_l=\frac{1}{2}2 \delta_{kl}a_l = a_k$$

using

$$\sum_{i=1}^3  \sum_{j=1}^3\epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{ijl}= 2\delta_{kl}$$ from Wikipedia (replace index name $n$ by $l$)

and applying Einstein's summation convention (summation over double-appearing indices).